# Load JavaScript file in angular2 app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, require, systemjs

I'm working on a angular2 application written in TypeScript.

### This works:

I have a module called `plugin-map.ts` which looks something like this:

```
import { Type } from '@angular/core';

import { SomeComponent } from './plugins/some.component';

export const PluginMap: { [key: string]: Type<any> } = {
    'e690bec6-f8d1-46a5-abc4-ed784e4f0058': SomeComponent
};
```

It gets transpiled to a `plugin-map.js` which looks something like this:

```
"use strict";
var some_component_1 = require('./plugins/some.component');
exports.PluginMap = {
    'e690bec6-f8d1-46a5-abc4-ed784e4f0058': some_component_1.SomeComponent
};
//# sourceMappingURL=plugin-map.js.map
```

And in other modules I'm importing my `PluginMap` like this:

```
import { PluginMap } from './plugin-map';
```

### What I want:

Now I want to create `plugin-map.js` at runtime when my server starts. So I want to get rid of my `plugin-map.ts` and instead have only a (generated) `plugin-map.js`. And I don't want to have any transpile-time dependencies to that `plugin-map.js`.

### What I tried:

In modules where I need to access the `PluginMap` I replaced the `import` statement with a declaration like this:

```
declare const PluginMap: { [key: string]: Type<any> };
```

Now of course at runtime I get a `Error: (SystemJS) 'PluginMap' is undefined`. So my next step was to load `plugin-map.js` explicitly from my `index.html` like this:

```
...
<script src="js/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
      System.import('./app/plugins/plugin-map.js').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
...
```

When I start my application I can see that the browser actually requests the `plugin-map.js` file. But I still get the `Error: (SystemJS) 'PluginMap' is undefined`.

### Question:

How/where do I have to load my generated `plugin-map.js` so that this works?

Comment: You're using SystemJS not RequireJS so I've edited your tags accordingly. Be careful with that because that can seriously harm your question's visibility.

Comment: Ok thanks for that edit! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to make sure that PluginMap is available in the global context. So the generated `plugin-map.js` has to look like this:

```
var some_component_1 = require('./plugins/some.component');
PluginMap = {
    'e690bec6-f8d1-46a5-abc4-ed784e4f0058': some_component_1.SomeComponent
};
```

and not like this:

```
"use strict";
var some_component_1 = require('./plugins/some.component');
exports.PluginMap = {
    'e690bec6-f8d1-46a5-abc4-ed784e4f0058': some_component_1.SomeComponent
};
//# sourceMappingURL=plugin-map.js.map
```

Now it seems to work.